# Should the tags 'framework' and 'frameworks' be merged?

Tags: discussion

There are just over 500 entries tagged '[framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework)' on SO, and just over 400 tagged '[frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frameworks)' (or maybe vice versa).  I rather suspect one such tag would do - I would probably select the singular over the plural, but I have no strong opinions on that issue.

(Amusing side-note: Meta has '[discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion)' and '[discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussions)' tags - only two entries under 'discussions' though).

Comment: Links. framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework
frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frameworks (I'd edit them in, but I lack the mojo on meta)

Comment: What is the obsession with fixing the tags? I'm curious

Comment: 15 question overlap.

Comment: @Oscar: there are a couple of reasons - (1) it makes it harder to search for questions about frameworks if there are two tags to search; (2) it makes it harder to keep my list of interesting tags under control if any of them have dual forms. Plus I suffer from a general obsession with tidiness in this sort thing - anal retentiveness. Pity is doesn't carry over to the physical world!  Also, as the related questions on the right show, there are lots of other 'merge these tags' questions/suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of them are asking about a given framework, but don't have the given framework as a tag.

for example:

- [Strataframe .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490456/strataframe-net-framework)

  Which currently has the tags `[frameworks]` `[framework]` `[visual-studio-2008]`
- [The Milos Framework from EPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458758/the-milos-framework-from-eps)

  currently tagged: `[frameworks]` `[framework]`
- [Web Development Frameworks: Zend Framework vs Ruby on Rails vs ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963532/web-development-frameworks-zend-framework-vs-ruby-on-rails-vs-asp-net-mvc)

  currently tagged `[web-development]` `[framework]` `[subjective]`

---

The questions that do have the given framework as a tag, don't really need either tag. They also usually have the `[framework]` tag immediately following the the name of the framework. Which suggests that they may have put the `[framework]` tag on without thinking about it.

- [Java Spring Modular Application Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480005/java-spring-modular-application-design)

  `[java]` `[spring]` `[framework]` `[web-development]`
- [Entity Framework - New entities with new children cannot be added with savechanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478072/entity-framework-new-entities-with-new-children-cannot-be-added-with-savechange)

  `[entity]` `[framework]` `[savechanges]` `[context]` `[c#]`
- [How to use Zend_Form in a layout script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477136/how-to-use-zendform-in-a-layout-script)

  `[zend]` `[framework]` `[form]`

---

There are some that seem to be appropriate to have `[framework]` as a tag.

- [RESTful framework alternatives to WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453174/restful-framework-alternatives-to-wcf)

  `[wcf]` `[restful]` `[framework]` `[.net]`
- [Is it efficient to use css frame works? If so, which one is best? Or any comparison comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450555/is-it-efficient-to-use-css-frame-works-if-so-which-one-is-best-or-any-comparis)

  `[css]` `[framework]` `[css-frameworks]`
- [ERP Framework to use in development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449503/erp-framework-to-use-in-development)

  `[erp]` `[framework]` `[enterprise-library]`

---

Then there are those that apparently just added the tag because it was there.

- [Anyone know the Click Framework ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439302/anyone-know-the-click-framework)

  `[framework]` `[apache]` `[click-framework]`

---

There are [3,789 questions that have a tag matching `[*framework*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~framework~) only [934 of them have either `[framework]` or `[frameworks]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework+or+frameworks).

---

I'm going to go out on a limb here, and question whether we even need either tag.

Answer (score 3):

Just scanning the titles I don't detect a distinction in usage. I'd say merge them to the singlular tag.

Answer (score 3):

The plural usage probably is used to indicate that the question involves more than one framework, possible for comparison or contrast purposes.  This is a common problem among such general-use tags. Compare also:

**Plural more common:**

- **packages** (115) vs **package** (59)
- **programming-languages** (853) vs **programming-language** (1)
- **functions** (427) vs **function** (420)
- **methods** (236) vs **method** (174)
- **namespaces** (293) vs **namespace** (162)
- **variables** (439) vs **variable** (180)

**Singular more common:**

- **language** (268) vs **languages** (52)
- **class** (802) vs **classes** (223)
- **library** (1101) vs **libraries** (16)
- **file** (928) vs **files** (760)

Maybe something else needs to be done wrt the plurality issue.

Comment: In a lot of those cases, both tags are wrong.  For example, Are you asking about `packages` or `packaging` (creating/maintaing packages)? If the former, it's probably not really a stackoverflow question.  Are you asking about a specific `file`, or are you trying to do `file-io`?

Comment: Good point.  Adds another wrinkle to an already confusing problem.  I guess more to the point is whether or not singular or plural should be preferred in the first place for the general case.  If so, a mass retagging can be done.  If *not*, then we're kinda stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Just merge them, any possible confusion should be cleared by the other tags of the question.